# How to import mail from Outlook.com to Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, export, migrate, outlook.com

I've recently switched from using Outlook.com for my business emails to Gmail for Business.

Does anyone know how I can migrate my old emails in Outlook.com to Gmail? I can't find any import or export functions on either site.

There is mention of using TrueSwitch, but that has been deactivated. Note: I need to migrate from Outlook.COM, not the desktop Outlook. Any assistance is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: would be more suitable on WebApps

Comment: Im having the same problem. Did you found a solution?

Comment: Hey Etienne, Sorry I just saw this and I did find a solution. I wrote it up here since it's kind of a long answer: http://robfine.com/MigrateOutlookComEmailsToGmail

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you own a computer: connect both accounts to your favorite e-mail client (e.g. Mozilla Thunderbird) via IMAP, and move or copy the folders from one account to the other. You'll also need a decent connection if you have a lot of data (your e-mail client downloads the old mailbox's contents to your computer and uploads it back to the new one).

As [@askchipbug says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077151/1424087):

- Install Thunderbird
- `Edit` > `Account settings`
- Bottom left `Account actions` > `Add mail account`
- Leave configuration as `IMAP (remote folders)`
- Repeat for your second account.
- Voila - both accounts AND folders appear in Thunderbird
- In your former account in Thunderbird, highlight the folders you want to copy
- Drag them to your other account
- Have a cup of tea while the emails/folders all copy over

Note: It may take a while for all your emails to be seen in all folders by Thunderbird...

Answer (score -2):

1) install thunderbird, like the man says.

2) edit > account settings

3) Bottom left account actions > add mail account

4) here's the kicker - leave configuration as IMAP ( remote folders)

5) repeat for your second account.

6) Voila - both accounts AND folders appear in thunderbird

7) In thunderbird, highlight the folders you want to copy

8) drag them to your other account.

9) have a cuppa while the emails/folders all copy over.

note: it took a while for all my emails to be seen in all folders by thunderbird...

Comment: Don't use answers as an alternative to comments. 13 rep is not hard to earn to be able to comment. Suggest you either make this a comment, or edit it and turn it into an actual answer - you seem to be adding some additional info in a guide-like way.